# converting phone numbers to vcf format algorithm

Tags: php, arrays, loops, vcf-vcard

From:

```
BOBBY,9238123
LOBBY,2312312
```

Into:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:BOBBY;;;;
FN:BOBBY
TEL;CELL:9238123
END:VCARD

BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
N:LOBBY;;;;
FN:LOBBY
TEL;CELL:3423423
END:VCARD
```

the bobby repeats twice and phone number once
This is what I have tried

my code:

```
foreach(explode("\n", $text) as $line) {
    // I don't know what to do next
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if a for loop with the comment "I don't know what do do next" actually counts as "have tried".

Comment: I agree with @Simon. For an attempt, I'd like to see some echo statements at least. Also, you already know how to explode on newline, so you could explode on comma in an inner loop, perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve the fields of each line using `str_getcsv()`.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php

Or just explode a second time:

```
foreach( explode( "\n", $text ) as $line )
{
    $fields = explode( ',', $line );
    var_dump( $fields );
}
```